# Error code: AADB2C90261 - Azure B2C/Captcha related Error on Sign Up

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, recaptcha, msal-angular

I am trying to sign up the users using Azure B2C(by doing this I am using MSAL with Angular),
by mail confirmation, captcha v2(google) and MFA.
For the first attempt I used just a normal sign up with the email and afterwards with MFA and had no issues creating the users.
Than I added captcha and in my sign-up, meaning that I needed to use a custom page.
To add captcha feature I used the following process from this link [Link - Create Captcha with Azure B2C](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-node-sign-up-user-flow-captcha) (regarding one step that is described in the article, the azure function was created in the portal, because locally I had some issues)
In my sign up page where you add the email address and all the claims of the user, after adding all the claims and checked the captcha feature, than press for create, appears the following message:

> errorCode: "AADB2C90261" message: "The claims exchange
> 'PreUserWriteRestful' specified in step '1' returned HTTP error
> response that could not be parsed." status: "400"

AADB2C90261 -Taken from Microsoft page - Error Code -  The claims exchange '{0}' specified in step '{1}' returned HTTP error response that could not be parsed.

Also the MFA feature doesn't appear. What can be ? that I missed to do ? Or what it represents ?
*Tested without MFA and the same issue persists*
Did anybody that is using Azure B2C added captcha ?

Thank you.

Comment: In your Azure function, have you modified any code in **[index.js](https://i.imgur.com/SPFO2yY.png)** file or left it default?

Comment: No I did not modify anything, I let it default, and as I stated this was done in the portal, because locally I cannot do it - function file [category](https://postimg.cc/2VV7S1sC) . Only difference that I am noticing that mine is using C sharp and the one presented by you is using js. I am gonna change the runtime stack to see if it works. Should be this a problem ?

Comment: Got the same error even with **js**  like ***[this,](https://i.imgur.com/H5rLLdT.png)*** will try modifying few things and get back to you.

Comment: Same, I don't know where it is the issue, but thanks for being interested of the subject.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got below results:***

Initially I deployed Azure Function via Portal and left ***index.js*** file as default like below:

[image]

I configured one API connector named **Verify Captcha** by adding above `function URL` in endpoint like below:

[image]

Now I added this **API connector** to my user flow like below:

[image]

When I ran the user flow by entering required details in `Sign up` page and checked the captcha feature, I got the **same error** as below:

[image]

To **resolve** the error, I tried deploying 2 Http Trigger Functions ***locally***:

**`HttpTrigger1`** - modified **index.js** file with this **[GitHub code](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-node-sign-up-user-flow-captcha/blob/main/CaptchaAzureFunction/index.js)**
and installed **required modules** like below:

[image]

**`HttpTrigger2`** - left  **index.js** file with default code like below:

[image]

By updating properties in **local.settings.json** file, I deployed these functions to Azure:

```json
{
"IsEncrypted": false,
"Values": {
"AzureWebJobsStorage": "",
"FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "node",
"BASIC_AUTH_USERNAME": "xxxxx",
"BASIC_AUTH_PASSWORD": "xxxxx",
"CAPTCHA_SECRET_KEY": "6LfoQ9oxxxxx21BEE23-kPQkv6QIQt8",
"B2C_EXTENSIONS_APP_ID": "dcxxx0b0-d5xf-42x-b1a4-97xxx689x1"
}
}
```

**Response:**

[image]

When I checked in **Azure Portal**, functions are updated successfully like below:

[image]

I configured another API connector named **Verify Captcha server side** by adding above `function URL` in endpoint like below:

[image]

Now I updated **API connector** with above in my user flow like below:

[image]

I ran the user flow by entering required details in `Sign up` page and checked the **captcha feature** like below:

[image]

When I selected **Create account**, I got response like below:

[image]

It may take some time to complete the **captcha** like below:

[image]

When I tried the same with default ***index.js*** like **`HttpTrigger2`**, I'm getting **same error** as you. So, make sure to replace code in your **index.js** file with this **[GitHub code.](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-node-sign-up-user-flow-captcha/blob/main/CaptchaAzureFunction/index.js)**

You can try the same in your environment ***locally*** to resolve the issue.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Honestly I don't how that function escaped from me, I thought that this should be default, but no. But to work I have to do it locally as you suggested than deploy it, with their azure function logic. If I do it only from the portal it won't work, even changing the azure function, probably will be needed more settings. I wanted to do it only from the portal because I cannot create app functions or group resources using vs code (I don't know why exactly, an error keeps appearing). But I created initially in the portal than created locally a function and deployed it after.

Comment: Now is appearing exactly how it's in the pictures set by you, but now seems there's another issue and is related more to the captcha by not seeing a complete check of the captcha. Still thank you for the help.